# Simple DLL injection not working using AppInit_DLLs. DllMain() not getting called

Tags: dll, dll-injection

I've written the simplest injection dll possible.  Here is the code in its entirety:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HANDLE hModule, 
                      DWORD  ul_reason_for_call, 
                      LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    FILE * File = fopen("D:\\test.txt", "w");
    if(File != NULL)
    {
        fclose(File);
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

Super simple right?  Well I can't even get this to work.  This code compiles to a dll and I've placed the path to this dll in the registry under [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows\AppInit_DLLs]. I should also mention that LoadAppInit_DLLs registry value is set to 1.  From doing this I expect to see the file "D:\test.txt" appear when I start other applications (like notepad.exe), but it doesn't.  I don't get it.  There is another .dll, which is very old and written in visual studio '97, (*which I'm trying to replace*) that works just fine when I set AppInit_DLLs to point to it and start an arbitrary application.  I can tell that it is getting loaded when other applications are started.

I'm not sure whats going on here, but this should work shouldn't it?  It can't get any simpler. I'm using VS 2010, by all accounts I think I've created a very plane Jane .dll so I don't think any project settings should be out of whack, but I'm not completely sure about that.  What am I missing here?

---

**Setup Info**

- OS: Windows 7 64-bit
- OS Version: 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1 Build 7601
- IDE: Visual Studio 2010
- IDE version: 10.0.40219.1 SP1Rel

Comment: I'll arbitrarily guess that you are trying this on a 64-bit version of Windows.  Use SysInternals' ProcMon to stop guessing.

Comment: Yes, I'm on Windows 7 64 bit. I've been starting 32 bit applications though since the AppInit_DLLs registry key I've been using is the 32-bit one.  I will add a section to my question were I'll keep information on my setup.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows\AppInit_DLLs]`
is **NOT** the registry key used for injection for into **32-bit processes**.  Its the registry key if your **OS is 32-bit**.

`[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows\AppInit_DLLs]` is the correct registry key to use if your **OS is 64-bit**.

I was under the *assumption* that the former was for 32-bit *processes* and the latter was for 64-bit *processes*.  But really, the OS is going to ignore one of those registry keys depending on whether or not the OS itself is 64-bit or 32-bit.

Comment: This is of course complicated by the fact that the 32-bit processes see a different view of the registry, whereby the *real* `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft` appears to be at `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft`

Answer (score 2):

@Ultratrunks: This is not completely correct.

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows\AppInit_DLLs ] is for both 32 as well as 64 bit OS.

But If we want to run 32 bit processes on 64 bit machine then we need to modify the following registry key-
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows\AppInit_DLLs]

Wow is basically concept of making 64 bit system to be compatible of running 32 bit processes.

I verified it after running my programs on both 32 as well as 64 bit OS and running 32 bit processes on 64 bit machine.

Hence

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows\AppInit_DLLs  for 32/64 bit OS

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows\AppInit_DLLs   for 32 bit processes on 64 bit OS

Answer (score 0):

First at all about the `SOFTWARE\Microsoft vs SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft`   it's true that if both 32 or 64 so go into `SOFTWARE\Microsoft` and if you want to inject 32 bit dll in `OS64` so go into `SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft`.

My problem was that the value need to be up to 8 characters and if there is in the path or name above this you need to use shortcut.

Example: if your dll name is `inject~1.dll`

Don't Forget to set all three reg value

1. `AppInit_DLL`s -> `dllname` if is in `system32` or full path with out "
2. `LoadAppInit_DLLs` -> 1
3. `RequireSignedAppInit_DLLs` -> 0